# How can I perform a two-sample multivariate t-test where one group is a subset of the other?

Tags: anova, t-test, multivariate-analysis, subset

Is it possible to compare two means (ideally multivariate) where one comes from a group that is the subset of the other group?

E.g. the first group consists of A, B, C, D, E subjects and the second one consists of A, B, C, D, E, F subjects. My goal is to test whether the F'th subject greatly impacts the result

Comment: This sounds more like an outlier test for F, than a test for comparing means. Would you agree?

Comment: @Greenparker what if each subject has repeated measures? (and what if there's more than one subject in difference?)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365244/find-if-two-groups-are-different-where-one-is-a-subset-of-the-other