# Find if two groups are different where one is a subset of the other

Tags: chi-squared-test, z-test

I have a dataset of 3,500,000 categorical observations that can be grouped by an ID. In these categories `u` occurs 25,000 times. How can I test to determine if a group has a different proportion of `u` compared with the whole dataset?

For example: a group has 2200 members where 300 have category `u`. What calculations would I make for this group?

Should I use a z-test or chi squared? Why/why not?

If I do this test for every group will I run into a multiple testing problem? Are there any other considerations I have missed?

Comment: It's best to compare the subset with its complement (sample of $2200,$ with $3,500,000 -2200$ others. One way is to make a $2 \times 2$ table with column headers Subset & Complement, column headers U & non-U, and appropriate counts in the four cells. Then do chi-squared test. // Another way is to compare proportion of U in subset with proportion of U in Complement using a z-test.

Answer (score 0):

In Minitab statistical software the printout for the z-test is shown below:
Essentially, your are comparing $\hat p_S = 0.135$ in your sample with
$\hat p_C = 0.007$ in the complement of the sample. Sample sizes are large
enough to find that these proportions are significantly different.

The difference 
$\hat p_S - \hat p_C$ is approximately normally distributed. When you divide
by an estimate of the standard deviation of this difference, you get a
test statistic $Z$ that is normally distributed. Here $Z = -17.66$ and you
can reject the null hypothesis that the two proportions are equal.
I suppose you can find a formula for this test in a statistics textbook
under 'Categorical Data: tests for two proportions'.

The last line of the output shows the results of Fisher's Exact test.
You can find a description of that test on Wikipedia, if not in a textbook.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample      X        N  Sample p
1       25000  3497600  0.007148
2         300     2200  0.136364


Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.129216
95% CI for difference:  (-0.143556, -0.114876)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -17.66  P-Value = 0.000

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.000
```

If you do a test for independence in a two-by-two 'contingency table' as
described in my Comment, you will reject the null hypothesis that
categories Sample/Complement and U/non-U are independent.